# Print unicode from formated string

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

How to print an unicode char from formated string ? With following example i have an error (python3):

```
 python -c 'print(u"\u{}".format("2665"))'
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"\u{}"` throws that error because the string representation `\unnnn` is not supposed to work with variables; it's a *literal, immediate value*. Much like you cannot do `x = 't'; print ('a\{}b'.format(x))` and expect a tab between `a` and `b`.

To print any Unicode character, either enter its literal code immediately into the string itself:

```
 print ('Hello \u2665 world')
```

result:

```
Hello ♥ world
```

– do note that you don't need the `u` prefix on the string itself; that's a Python 2.x'ism –, or, if you want to provide the character value in a variable:

```
print ('Hello {:c} world'.format(0x2665))
```

where (1) the `:c` forces a *character representation* of the value, and (2) you need to indicate that the value itself is in hex. (As the string representation `\unnnn` is *always* in hex.)

Answer (score 4):

It's kind of awkward, but you can use a raw string literal, encode, and then decode back using the `unicode_escape` encoding:

```
print(r"\u{}".format("2665").encode().decode('unicode_escape'))
#  ♥
```